# keras Concatenate mulitple layers cause AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to add some fixed [kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) in my CNN, please see my codes below.

This is how I create my kernels:

```
# Kernels
def create_kernel(x):
    t = pipe(
        x, 
        lambda x: tf.constant(x, dtype=tf.float32), 
        lambda x: tf.reshape(x, [3, 3, 1, 1]))
    return t

k_edge1 = create_kernel([1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1])
k_edge2 = create_kernel([0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0])
k_edge3 = create_kernel([-1, -1, -1, -1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

and my convolution network is like:

```
# Convolution network
# Input layer
l_input = Input(shape=(28**2, ))
# Reshape layer
l_reshape = Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1))(l_input)
# Convolution layers
l_conv1 = Conv2D(filters=20, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='valid')(l_reshape)
l_edge1 = tf.nn.conv2d(l_reshape, k_edge1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
l_edge2 = tf.nn.conv2d(l_reshape, k_edge2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
l_edge3 = tf.nn.conv2d(l_reshape, k_edge3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
l_conv1a = Concatenate(axis=3)([l_conv1, l_edge1, l_edge2, l_edge3])  # <- The error should be caused by this line.
l_conv2 = Conv2D(filters=20, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='valid')(l_conv1a)
l_pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), border_mode='valid')(l_conv2)
# Flatten layer
l_flat = Flatten()(l_pool1)
# Fully connected layers
l_fc1 = Dense(50, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(l_flat)
l_act1 = PReLU()(l_fc1)
l_fc3 = Dense(10, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(l_act1)
l_output = Activation('softmax')(l_fc1)

# Model
cnn_model = Model(l_input, l_output)
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 237, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1353, in _map_graph_network
    tensor_index=tensor_index)
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1340, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1340, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1340, in build_map
    node_index, tensor_index)
[Previous line repeated 2 more times]
File "C:\Users\Perry Cheng\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ml_py_3_6\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 1312, in build_map
    node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

After some testing, I think the error comes from:

```
l_conv1a = Concatenate(axis=3)([l_conv1, l_edge1, l_edge2, l_edge3])
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: You can't use TF functions directly on Keras tensors, you need to pass them through a Lambda layer. And I don't see why you have to use tf.nn.conv2d instead of just a Conv2D layer.

Comment: So is there a way to use my fixed custom kernel using `Conv2D`? From my understanding, the kernels in `Conv2D` are needed to be trained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras layers accepts Keras Tensors and not Tensors as their input. So if you would like to use `tf.nn.conv2d` instead of `Conv2D` layers in Keras, you need to wrap them inside a `Lambda` layer:

```
l_edge1 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.conv2d(x, k_edge1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID'))(l_reshape)
l_edge2 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.conv2d(x, k_edge2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID'))(l_reshape)
l_edge3 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.conv2d(x, k_edge3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID'))(l_reshape)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use TF functions directly on Keras tensors as you are doing here:

```
l_edge1 = tf.nn.conv2d(l_reshape, k_edge1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
l_edge2 = tf.nn.conv2d(l_reshape, k_edge2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
l_edge3 = tf.nn.conv2d(l_reshape, k_edge3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
```

What you should do is to just use the Conv2D layer and then set the weights manually using `layer.set_weights(array)`. To keep weights non-trainable, just set `layer.trainable = False`, like:

```
conv = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size(3, 3), padding='valid')
conv.set_weights(your_weight_array)
conv.trainable = False

l_edge1 = conv(l_reshape)
```

And similarly for the other two Conv2D layers.