# GAN RNN generator: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm writing an LSTM Generative Adversarial Network, where the generator takes in a sequence (`starting_seqs`) of length 3, and predicts the next element in the sequence, and use the last 3 elements in the sequence as the new input, and repeats until we have a sequence of length 20.

But it seems that the Lambda layer is not configured properly..?

```
def build_generator():
    generator = Sequential()
    generator.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(3, 6))) # (len_timestep, n_feature)
    generator.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True))
    generator.add(LSTM(6, activation='softmax'))
    starting_seqs = Input(shape=(3, 6))
    input_seqs = starting_seqs
    gen_seqs = tf.reshape(starting_seqs, shape=[1, 3, 6])

    for i in range(17):
        input_seqs = tf.reshape(input_seqs, shape=[1, 3, 6])
        gen_nexts = tf.one_hot(tf.nn.top_k(generator(input_seqs)).indices, 6)
        gen_seqs = Concatenate(axis=1)([gen_seqs, gen_nexts])
        input_seqs = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-3:,])(gen_seqs)
    return Model(starting_seqs, gen_seqs)
```

**edit:** I tried @today 's suggestion and changed the for loop to this, while still getting the same error/stack trace:

```
for i in range(17):
    gen_nexts_idx = Lambda(lambda x: generator(tf.reshape(x, shape=[1, 3, 6])))(input_seqs)
    gen_nexts = Lambda(lambda x: tf.one_hot(tf.nn.top_k(x).indices, 6))(gen_nexts_idx)
    gen_seqs = Concatenate(axis=1)([gen_seqs, gen_nexts])
    input_seqs = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,-3:,])(gen_seqs)
```

Stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-99cf619fabcf> in <module>()
     69 
     70 optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)
---> 71 generator = build_generator()
     72 discriminator = build_discriminator()
     73 discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)

<ipython-input-31-99cf619fabcf> in build_generator()
     66 
     67         # input_seqs = tf.slice(gen_seqs, [0, gen_seqs.shape[1].value-3, 0], [1, 3, 6])
---> 68     return Model(starting_seqs, gen_seqs)
     69 
     70 optimizer = Adam(0.0002, 0.5)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     91                 'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
     92             # Graph network
---> 93             self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
     94         else:
     95             # Subclassed network

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name)
    229         # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
    230         nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, layers_by_depth = _map_graph_network(
--> 231             self.inputs, self.outputs)
    232         self._network_nodes = nodes
    233         self._nodes_by_depth = nodes_by_depth

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
   1364                   layer=layer,
   1365                   node_index=node_index,
-> 1366                   tensor_index=tensor_index)
   1367 
   1368     for node in reversed(nodes_in_decreasing_depth):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1351             tensor_index = node.tensor_indices[i]
   1352             build_map(x, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer,
-> 1353                       node_index, tensor_index)
   1354 
   1355         finished_nodes.add(node)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in build_map(tensor, finished_nodes, nodes_in_progress, layer, node_index, tensor_index)
   1323             ValueError: if a cycle is detected.
   1324         """
-> 1325         node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
   1326 
   1327         # Prevent cycles.

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: @roganjosh Added! The network is built recursively so there is a lot of repetition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keras Concatenate mulitple layers cause AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '\_inbound\_nodes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850105/keras-concatenate-mulitple-layers-cause-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no)

Comment: @sqd Wrap those `tf` functions inside a `Lambda` layer. Take a look at the answers to the linked question I posted above.

Comment: @today It doesn't work. Please see my edit.

Comment: @sqd Did you do the same for the `tf.reshape` which is right before the `for` loop?

Comment: @today now it works! Thanks a lot!